# Track email transfers logs

Tags: outlook, ms-office

> Hello everyone,

My collegue always transfer my emails willingly to spam folder...
Is it possible please to show email auditing ?

Thank you so much

Comment: Your colleague filters emails from you to go to the spam folder?

Comment: Yes, but i want to proove it, is it possible in outlook ?

Comment: Is there any possibility to view email positions such as : arrived at date 1, moved to spam at date 2, deleted at date 3....?????